# When $X_n \to c$, $(y^{X_n})^n \to (y^c)^{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

We know that for $t > 0$, $t^n \to 0$ or $\infty$, depending on $t < 1$ or not. (Let's not consider $t=1$ case)

My question is that when $X_n \to c$ almost surely for some constant, can we say the following almost surely??
\begin{equation}
(t^{X_n})^n \to \begin{cases}
(t^c)^{\infty} = 0 && if ~~~~t^c < 1\\
(t^c)^{\infty} = \infty && if ~~~~ t^c > 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I am aware of the continuous mapping theorem, but not sure this is applicable here since outer function is discontinuous at limit. I think the claim is true, but to show "rigorously", I have no idea.

Note: here $X_n \to c$ exponentially fast.

Comment: But $t$ is fixed right? So, $g_t(X_n)=t^{nX_n}$ and apply the theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y_n = (t^{X_n})^n=t^{nX_n}$. Consider taking the logarithm based $t$, define $Z_n = \log_t(Y_n)=nX_n$.

For every $\omega$, the sequence $Y_n(\omega)$ converges if and only if $Z_n(\omega)$ converges. Hence it suffices to study $Z_n$. If $c>0$, $Z_n\to\infty$ almost surely; if $c<0$, $Z_n\to -\infty$ almost surely. If $c=0$, $Z_n\to 0$ almost surely by the rate of convergence of $X_n$.

Can you deduce the limits of $Y_n$?